# How to use HTML img srcset in fluid layout?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a web page design where the layout size and image sizes are based on em's. For example:

```
<html style="width:50em; font-size:16pt">
  <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum
      <img src="..." style="float:right; width:20em">
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because the image size is specified in em's, it is always in lockstep with the text size. Unfortunately, we don't know how many CSS pixels wide an image is. We also don't know how many device pixels wide an image is, which depends on the size of an em, the magnification, etc.

The `<img>` `srcset` and `sizes` attributes appear to be nearly the solution I want. But I'm not sure if it applies to my situation here. I can generate multiple asset sizes, e.g. 320×240, 480×360, 640×480, etc.

**I want the web browser to look at the content box for the `<img>` element, calculate how many device pixels wide it is, and download the most appropriate image from a list of alternatives.** How can I do this?

Note: I did read about the `srcset` `x` syntax, but it doesn't seem to be the right tool.

Comment: I learned a lot by checking out [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) article. Does the image size scale with the viewport, or will be in lockstep with the sizes via media queries?

Comment: The code I included is basically represents the entire situation. I am not doing media queries or viewport-based image scaling.

Comment: you could use min-width and max-width in % or vw units to make sure it fits in the range of the screen. Have you tried to set these ? .. aside srcet , else can you get rid off : width XXem ? *em doesn't care of viewport*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Eric Portis's article](https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/), this solves the problem:

```
<img style="width:20em" sizes="20em"
    src="pic-1000.png"
    srcset="
        pic-150.png 150w,
        pic-220.png 220w,
        pic-330.png 330w,
        pic-470.png 470w,
        pic-680.png 680w,
        pic-1000.png 1000w">
```

After the web page is loaded, if the most appropriate image changes for some reason (e.g. using zoom to change the device pixel ratio), then Firefox will always change the image to the most appropriate one at the moment. By contrast, Chrome seems to change the image if the new one is bigger, but won't change to a small image unless you reload the page - the image resolution is sticky upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Srcset is definitely a great way to approach this. You basically have a number of images you save out for multiple sizes, usually you'll want to have the image be the same width of the element if possible. Then you set the image that you want to use for each screen width.

```
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Name"
  srcset="
    /img-2400.jpg 2400w,
    /img-1800.jpg 1800w,
    /img-1200.jpg 1200w,
    /img-900.jpg 900w,
    /img-600.jpg 600w,
    /img-400.jpg 400w"
  sizes = "(min-width: 2400px) 900px,
           (min-width: 1800px) 600px,
           (min-width: 1200px) 500px,
           (min-width: 900px) 500px,
           (min-width: 600px) 600px,
           400px" />
```

So `/img-2400.jpg 2400w` would use `/img-2400.jpg` when the screen is closest to `2400px` wide.

In the sizes attribute, you can also specify if what the image size will be at certain screen sizes as it may not always be 100% of the width of the browser.

So `(min-width: 2400px) 900px` is telling the browser that when the window is at least `2400px` wide, the image will be `900px` wide on the screen. So that should be telling the browser to then grab `/img-900.jpg` when the window is `2400px` wide since that image is set to `900w` which is the closest to `900px` (its exact).

You can still approximately calculate this if you are using em, by multiplying the em you are using by 16 (this may vary depending on browser settings or settings you impose in your css). So if you set your width of an image in css to be `20em`, thats `16 * 20 = 320px`.

When these are used in combination, modern browsers should be able to detect the best image to grab dependent on the screen size. See browser compatability for srcset here: https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset